# Pressing a key in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm developing a program that searches for a running program and press a button on it automatically But How can I press the enter key on the keyboard from my code (send the command of the enter key)?
         Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx).

Please check [**this CodeProject tutorial**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SendKeys.aspx) for detailed How To.

[image]